# NodeJs shared objects between processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a caching module for Nodejs that needs to utilize multiple CPUs using sub processes.

[image: possible setup]

I would like to store data in an index in the master process or, preferably in a subprocess like so:

```
var index = { key1: 21, key2: 22, key3: 55 }
```

and another process should be able to search in that index as efficiently as:

```
if('key2' in index) // do stuff
```

I assume using IPC would be significantly slower than achieving shared objects. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund I could but that's not what this module is about :D

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos were you able to find a solution that worked for you? I'm looking for people to try out the writable version of mmap-object....

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try [mmap-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmap-object). It coordinates shared memory based on a memory-mapped file which means the data is persistent as well as shared among processes. I wrote it so to avoid both the performance and management overhead of redis or a similar solution.

For your application the [read-write version](https://github.com/allenluce/mmap-object/tree/writable) may be what you want.

Comment: This seems to be a great solution @Allen...would you still suggest mmap-object for production today?

Comment: Certainly @LucaFagioli, it's still in use backing plenty of high-volume (production) services. Even six years on I've yet to see a package that hits all the same high points.

Comment: I will try it then, I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: It's working fine, I just do not understand how the memory is allocated. Why an utf8 buffer of 1,000,000 characters takes almost 3MB? I am working with very large files, so memory usage is important in this case.

Comment: HI @LucaFagioli, you may wish to post an actual question with some details of your usage. Issues around [Buffers in Node.JS](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.10/d6/dd4/classv8_1_1_array_buffer_1_1_allocator.html) can be complex.

Comment: Hi @Allen, I did: [mmap-object-and-memory-usage-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75591875/mmap-object-and-memory-usage-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I would use redis in your case. There are ways to configure redis on how frequently it will store its memory data on disk based on how many entries are saved or just time (http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

Another option might be to send requests between instances to save that memory data only on master.

When a non master instance wants to save or load data it will request the master.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
var SharedMemory = {
  storeObject: function(args, done) {
    if (IAmMaster()) {
      storeObjectToMemory(args);
      done();
    } else {
      sendRequestToMasterForSave(args, done);
    }
  },
  getObject: function(args, done) {
    if (IAmMaster()) {
      done(getObjectFromMemory(args));
    } else {
      getResponseFromMasterForLoad(args, done);
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is probably gonna be a painful process