# mmap-object and memory usage issue

Tags: node.js, boost

I have a large (ASCII) text file that I want to store as a memory-mapped file in Node.js, and I am using the `mmap-object` module to do so. However, I am having trouble understanding how to allocate the appropriate amount of memory when creating a new mmap-object instance.

The text file is a list of entries, each one separated by a newline character, and I want to store each line as a property in the shared object. Here's the method signature for creating a new shared object using mmap-object:

```js
new Create(path, [file_size], [initial_bucket_count], [max_file_size]);
```

I know the number of lines in the text file, so I am using that value for the `initial_bucket_count` parameter. However, I'm not sure what value to use for the `file_size` parameter.

This is how I am currently creating a shared object with `mmap-object`:

```js
const sharedObject = new Shared.Create(filePath, textFileSizeInKByte * 2, linesCount);
```

For each line in the text file, I have tried to store the line content in two ways:

```js
let lineIndex = 0;

for await (const line of rl) {

    // Option 1: Store the line as an ASCII-encoded buffer
    sharedObject[lineIndex] = Buffer.from(line, "ascii");

    // Option 2: Store the line as a regular string
    sharedObject[lineIndex] = line;

    lineIndex++;
}
```

However, in both cases, the memory-mapped file ends up being much larger than the original text file. I understand that there will be some overhead, but for text files of around 220MB, the memory usage can be up to twice the file size, and for larger text files of around 2.5GB, the memory usage can be up to five times the file size.

Can anyone help me understand why the memory usage is so much higher than the file size, and how I can reduce the amount of memory used by the memory-mapped file?

### Update 1

This is the complete test code:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import readline from "readline";
import Shared from "mmap-object";

const units = ["bytes", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"];

function niceBytes(x) {
    let l = 0,
        n = parseInt(x, 10) || 0;

    while (n >= 1024 && ++l) {
        n = n / 1024;
    }

    return n.toFixed(n < 10 && l > 0 ? 1 : 0) + " " + units[l];
}

const getFormattedBytes = (x) => {
    return `${x} (${niceBytes(x)})`;
};

export const loadMasterFile = async (filePath) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        throw `Error while loading math file: ${filePath} not found.`;
    }

    const { size } = fs.statSync(filePath);

    console.log(`Text file size: ${getFormattedBytes(size)}`);

    const sizeInKByte = Math.ceil(size / 1000);

    console.log(`Analysing master ${filePath} on pid ${process.pid}...`);

    const linesCount = await countFileLines(filePath);

    const sharedObject = new Shared.Create(`${filePath}.map`, sizeInKByte * 2, linesCount);

    console.log(`Lines count: ${linesCount}`);

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity,
    });

    let lineIndex = 0;

    for await (const line of rl) {
        if (lineIndex % 100000 === 0) {
            process.stdout.clearLine();
            process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
            process.stdout.write(`${lineIndex}`);
        }

        // const buffer = Buffer.alloc(line.length, "a", "ascii");
        // sharedObject[lineIndex] = buffer;
        sharedObject[lineIndex] = line;

        lineIndex++;
    }

    process.stdout.clearLine();
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    console.log(`\nMaster file for ${filePath} successfully analysed.\n`);

    console.log(`RSS: ${getFormattedBytes(process.memoryUsage().rss)}`);
    console.log(`HeapTotal: ${getFormattedBytes(process.memoryUsage().heapTotal)}`);
    console.log(`HeapUsed: ${getFormattedBytes(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed)}`);
    console.log(`External: ${getFormattedBytes(process.memoryUsage().external)}`);
    console.log(`arrayBuffers: ${getFormattedBytes(process.memoryUsage().arrayBuffers)}`);
};

function countFileLines(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let lineCount = 0;
        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .on("data", (buffer) => {
                let idx = -1;
                lineCount--; // Because the loop will run once for idx=-1
                do {
                    idx = buffer.indexOf(10, idx + 1);
                    lineCount++;
                } while (idx !== -1);
            })
            .on("end", () => {
                resolve(lineCount);
            })
            .on("error", reject);
    });
}

loadMasterFile("/tmp/6335da6e11e8463786ac0af7");
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
Text file size: 231196678 (220 MiB)
Analysing master /tmp/6335da6e11e8463786ac0af7 on pid 80910...
Lines count: 1303210

Master file for /tmp/6335da6e11e8463786ac0af7 successfully analysed.

RSS: 549629952 (524 MiB)
HeapTotal: 63807488 (61 MiB)
HeapUsed: 24416160 (23 MiB)
External: 6406499 (6.1 MiB)
arrayBuffers: 4591419 (4.4 MiB)
```

Note that when I create the shared object, on this line:

```js
const sharedObject = new Shared.Create(`${filePath}.map`, sizeInKByte * 2, linesCount);
```

I have to pass `sizeInKByte * 2` as `file_size` otherwise the process takes ages because the mapped file must be dynamically inflated to accommodate the whole data.

I obtain similar results by storing an ASCII encoded buffer (which should take 1 byte for every character) instead of the actual String.

### Update 2

This is the kind of content I intend to store (only the first 10 lines):

```
6wjZagsBmTxY3xeMc4brVplX72EgDB1RqLYg1M0GAVRrfESAEXAaIGafxAHZGU5WzAGXCBIeQjgv1pmQRsqy4TOAzn2OozJvNpnIvDqYiZply7V0mOFR34tZenbWD7S2nmhoNf0gGWicrQDQg6Lpk0QeLVv9q07R5bxZFT1BOE2NKWo7nQOdhZ0ADXMZD0bVeZe15HzdX1LzUgY4heBsvHyf7byNZLsjr4Dx88D6WxZ3okFynPuRNScfcDcD49byc4FLLAByV136TQJtw4xvyVC7wqgAQ9WD8sQyZ45i3hXXjb4AJgOlQQUxZwEZQVODqrg0Q9poSMTWrrvBZGRL1oRSnrQIz9H0zknLDpZ3SMPFgjVWUV3CGlNgsfQwQty0ie37
bWw4FBK0iKnncEPDcz7weEMwZpxy2gkNdx3lcGCGmWq1RuPXeAaM6UHVIsKymMVSQo15bFZGNebYFsiqEwbkwXbDZC7YRubpBfl1G9fvsh500U9S9qYuVEFjqVeyMK74cUg8wwX8cyDKOuUnAea4qk8ul1YIcpnlLdTSr8ZHembQzS6D1y4dBILIUaw9AepFDDABJP9JEUKo7466zvuDxINBnUFQ4EKkVwE5ODK0RyZcKzjixTXa7xVCd6TGBunmihuK0PV21ri9uq8t8geaH9qf2mk3iROsLs0fn2TuX3n0o0dNnWOqJQZRoKFvt1Uaxb9F8DuNBDab31qwPovmSXEbATTlILoepc8axKszGh4uajOHrQSYGcfTZapoD9E
SV8vv04gI3Gj3FRmHb4mxHqOE4aDxkI6sCRvNPIFtCpSibKL7TM69c3vbRIiaylJQXvUprm9oIgZ1cByTaJmdbBmElQ8boGA2FNtCX5RbqqlkgV0dt5nHnIS9pKpxcjvIp6zzbNTi3U6FpC0BfZYxSi2wvv8DPdUrxJRIHrrOW9yVMkfbIpqnxFxfktI6JNWe1vsUMmCRg8FvbLrEmoArTeWo9P6ttDUaLYy1TGEiljMOVgIxipulvWVZ1JyjG2qBTzZ8IlcQjZHGcZTtd5zaYbDFnLGgbIyyOtvKizAGSgh4B0sSNn5jai3wZyu7wpVPu0f3EtednG04Vinb6Ni2nQq2dSQ3NDMnSRaiwy5UWLA6hhMAXvBH8ROoBeRQ5I8vP
pZRs0sdNmMqbGSWDvxb1Jsj71NTouhiMlzUVQHc0zuXPgg9HxfkbDcbqOYi7XfnA2jhlzGMgHBWgh7yMtjVwhnHRp1OWVL70ea34OzOVPkj6TI4oHTBgdAlpbvwjK6ddK2seraJ3Qg038bk901lhOwnAW8KkCIXksaaHxJyphqtqG1Ygj6LWnGeKfDX6YAYIkr3H87PYmkqcUEpuQRGcDWnak7jROHGskwe5nLahgBgvwLjGneeZUGt73RG9vc2davWuVzxm2S8OuonMht4wTgr3fkWIVoMSm4AmpNdNLv8XZkxZeCEZAOS0a0HYvDFQtasSE08rCyOq9FenRtCJnSpSLVlj9vlFy47372agDFoPJq8fUnKxlTWbzVpdrPPpNnC1
CfUhWMF60Y1aMRlweRlcDa9qV9ikLG46UrwC5WHm6QY3kVvHG735FcKXSlbcBVanjwGw2jIz13IjjMNYJJCvz0rngpLUOZNhgCSyp5v3kHwrxgAP8opULdFsPCAsAIpexUFeYZbiLFfgmzzWsWmnrvz0f8P9CNcgUvr84HZwA2v358F6tdZDMkPxmaWEd3oPUo5fRRALn30clPizFEErSxy18zzor9FD1tlgCvfAaF0naq3EUeeZ1UgT8CHtw1YyiTfYbuUZXIbkaH6JHrVvNASCFWJB0EYvWrqTzVwKdsgWtgbpPlCucUn31VBGcKLTRxqkPpb1NJ4zxBhUKiXgCXtS6QMEPBNwwyPiQ5XXOwle4Zjq6vs5KudKOaIFrn5h0cyEpBJt
aVKC76KbvNFC63C3tAeBOepnS6qqXivjR60b4BjAdOk7FrFs0cioRdol8cVS6SWDotLXEGF1UInPF2NmVrX1S60zlrk8jK4QdlW348UISqWY0HhowVsm7y0z0UpeupFbceCOqLeNWRYvnOCS8zeEPg4ybd5U1mEGXlBbF5qLsdNyLdps89w1ryH8zP8gKf7VLF9AA9lefI9nX9TzPffQbdKJEVIb1UHCUlH7V0rTpb7hdq7Kx3NTKgAPN39aifVhdzVtwmKz5GRM4SSqepAx5dUlfDeA7EGzyO63prpkdWhPxexihc7WIJn5IxyQXaidvjBSOudMIH7AMhy6qZ9CESNEcO7e4cgmT2YxnicWGPicuf2eRG8wBuSpm5LJCgwAylvRiul
nhOhhXqVkBLlvuAoov6Cj1y1s0halCbfKJkDWsWtyn5mFvaUfZo6SLHfu9c4SEzacPsC2OxG4Vqna7ZwOJ5xzuWqjRZd9v2CyHmlvPnnCngGHYWHzhPf8v1tOXGRzSDOHWo01uf0W8zF2VlVEYU4llaAmEsRncD0Kup0fliqW2Epm50XhCAN9ldX5DgTWnIY7ZGv9EUALjyKIKVrSQFbSixdVbSn1NFx8yOk9XWOwTUeswjGc77fR95oYWQ1ajJPsQReiMDQ93Cogig1cJdXmKTptBUMyn29CGY0KRzd2UhgR1jxsNOGzgnKSoZOBjYiJYQpJKPznvvWoxMX9STSDofipwNSUcgK8EMCzZMSrwRCC2ilv8jil3YlXxmKgtHleo
zg2vcVrSeJp50Qvs1GwhqCcJT2QndGyPv2acnbKIrJZQcAKadNmGHH3tMdFpAA1swvjLv8Hkt9sQEUysqjTwi329nrDSeM9MlZGYGrBWxeWGRH6xPogrx8sfrhrEw5P0bQGDwgzQaqCvEhUWMWoS9zl6tZQQd1lM6KtMyKxwETJmc7lyYF7E9ZybrCJbPdtmEXMOnBLURnwvM58zc1fQJgTcfpvaC6t13o1NvkAa7LqfOKoSNbj6mKNDIwjEEOKRgLepxnGErQNNje24RwUzJx3ys80Cg9jKYdOztJvpZ4zmnblvcR3hJwD48tosCJQYVQMzLni1c4hsmJM72E9NUXpZjpPegNRFHbFMSI4w3tzomhzyoGEM3wLhtUVpYk0n2
xyDDaNotGOS0x4zGbXWpHfKmlmXEDAIXUj8RlgtavXJtjYIAPvy0CbniXPbiMW1aC5RA0RwDTs6js9uI0ztxBxTa1MP0Hw4Z4iTVrGTfukbvkk53MFVfTIJI8bSilsXNDho4BPZMqKo5b3dx3OQ59VQ8j3YwqlP6OSs6vgHxnPYNclS2MyRAWqxsSk9Wbur1kDtrS9Vbnh9VusTWo2KkvR93uShWjZ5knjDe3f6D3bBAGPfX3ArDZdMvoswdkQf1HlMtswtJRfF06xkqNAoaQRnYkWIJDpf1KsCuoc3s5Anvb9pbLdhv8oOntuUxc59OTAkaJ8VClYQoI4PGbn6h5NUiY18pZWufXrf2QS6t2hXjMJkdiG8OQtrQwEFIOoHD2u
mvkref3kq5VwOcCusoeOD2KJN6poRYFmNW5WCrMtRhrI8VMVlxxACmHyCc4xQrbHlcAo39et0bU4h97enzzUhs8GF44aqPx2EeLK8mKOJh8xeYFWOuaZq445pX3XRCdQeMAUm1IdtuPUoar5qbBVKMgKse9CwprLYmrPQ4ZNX3R4uRz5Q6ajYGvO9phcDIdMiBUArGw2GNadKMHzY0RgrVHeAGne7D6dfnB63ihBk35waW1oj6TKmaTqfD6O5OIQhXw9Dh157UCbQ7PcjwQwl8n0WBK8zDXioFoy6PqLharFuX1bNqr0OG9oVias7xZiqySzCGuQrp9HZAL5neSSAe0sRL9ILkMgjGV9bim5zkMx9HEqLUc4SW4qRIazZN1J
```

### Update 3

I have created a [test application](https://github.com/monteiz/mmap-object-memory-issue) to replicate the problem and created an [issue on the mmap-object github repository](https://github.com/allenluce/mmap-object/issues/39).

Comment: Hi Luca, can you demonstrate how you are measuring memory usage?

Comment: Hi @Allen, I have updated my answer with the whole code and how I am measuring the memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please illustrate what contents you mean? It's highly unusual to memory-map non-random access files, so perhaps you mean to /read from a text file/ into /a different datastructure inside shared memory/.

If so, consider a segment manager with a well-chosen data structure:

```
using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;
template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K>>
using Map    = bc::flat_map<K, V, Cmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;
using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using Dict   = Map<String, String>;

bool load_from_textfile(std::string const& fname, Dict& into);
void dump_table(Dict const& d);

int main() {
    Segment mapping(bip::open_or_create, "mapped.file", 30ull << 30);
    auto&   dict = *mapping.find_or_construct<Dict>("shared_table")(mapping.get_segment_manager());
    dict.emplace("Hello world", "Bye");
    load_from_textfile("input.txt", dict);
    dump_table(dict);
}
```

Here, we'll implement dumping using libfmt:

```
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
// teach libfmt to print shared strings
template <typename... T>
struct fmt::formatter<bc::basic_string<T...>> : fmt::formatter<std::string_view> {};

void dump_table(Dict const& d) {
    // fmt::print("shared table: {}\n", d);
    fmt::print("shared table:\n - {}\n", fmt::join(d, "\n - "));
}
```

And we'll read [a textfile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63dbf1eac8ace16b) like:

```
tumid=peyote titbit bemusing Alpert
"obsesses contains = equals sign"=Leila
epicures
midterm
pirates
pads
bobcat
cognac
docket        = abrade synchs councilwomen
epilepsy      = dawdled AC capitulated
freelances    = plenteous sloops above
watchers      = disproving tiaras unbinding
drudging      = scamps unbearable hydrology
temporized    = dart custodian dissimulating
Wilcox        = coopered initiated overprinting
Hazlitt       = amphibious soulful opts
chiropractics = month invocations Laue
Fm            = coin slime conspirator
Goya          = slender included embroiled
taxidermist   = Buckingham spates hairlines
sadists       = perfidious gibe Leiden
godless       = welted assiduous negation
spacier       = snorkels airfoil noisier
robocalled    = Glover snuffers magnified
Kirsten       = spotters Rojas lounging
creepy        = asseverating phased overflows
vertebrates   = propensities somewhats cinchonas
meaningless   = tinsel bewitching photojournalist
halogens      = routing runes necklines
alligator     = anus avid
```

And the output is: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72878642359804ca)**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc  = boost::container;

using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;
template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K>>
using Map    = bc::flat_map<K, V, Cmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;
using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using Dict   = Map<String, String>;

bool load_from_textfile(std::string const& fname, Dict& into);
void dump_table(Dict const& d);

int main() {
    Segment mapping(bip::open_or_create, "mapped.file", 30ull << 30);
    auto&   dict = *mapping.find_or_construct<Dict>("shared_table")(mapping.get_segment_manager());
    dict.emplace("Hello world", "Bye");
    load_from_textfile("input.txt", dict);
    dump_table(dict);
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
// teach libfmt to print shared strings
template <typename... T>
struct fmt::formatter<bc::basic_string<T...>> : fmt::formatter<std::string_view> {};

void dump_table(Dict const& d) {
    // fmt::print("shared table: {}\n", d);
    fmt::print("shared table:\n - {}\n", fmt::join(d, "\n - "));
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

bool load_from_textfile(std::string const& fname, Dict& into) { using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    using boost::fusion::at_c;

    bip::file_mapping  text(fname.c_str(), bip::read_only);
    bip::mapped_region region(text, bip::read_only);
    auto f = static_cast<char const*>(region.get_address()), l = f + region.get_size();

    using namespace x3;
    auto str   = [](auto expr) { return rule<struct _, std::string>{} = expr; };
    auto key   = str(lexeme['"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"'] | +~char_("=\r\n"));
    auto value = str(-('=' >> lexeme[*(char_ - eol)]));
    auto line  = key >> value;

    auto insert = [&into](auto& ctx) {
        into.emplace(at_c<0>(_attr(ctx)), at_c<1>(_attr(ctx)));
    };

    return phrase_parse(f, l, (line[insert] % x3::eol) >> x3::eoi, x3::blank);
}
```

Printing

```
shared table:
 - ("Fm", "coin slime conspirator")
 - ("Goya", "slender included embroiled")
 - ("Hazlitt", "amphibious soulful opts")
 - ("Hello world", "Bye")
 - ("Kirsten", "spotters Rojas lounging")
 - ("Wilcox", "coopered initiated overprinting")
 - ("alligator", "anus avid")
 - ("bobcat", "")
 - ("chiropractics", "month invocations Laue")
 - ("cognac", "")
 - ("creepy", "asseverating phased overflows")
 - ("docket", "abrade synchs councilwomen")
 - ("drudging", "scamps unbearable hydrology")
 - ("epicures", "")
 - ("epilepsy", "dawdled AC capitulated")
 - ("freelances", "plenteous sloops above")
 - ("godless", "welted assiduous negation")
 - ("halogens", "routing runes necklines")
 - ("meaningless", "tinsel bewitching photojournalist")
 - ("midterm", "")
 - ("obsesses contains = equals sign", "Leila")
 - ("pads", "")
 - ("pirates", "")
 - ("robocalled", "Glover snuffers magnified")
 - ("sadists", "perfidious gibe Leiden")
 - ("spacier", "snorkels airfoil noisier")
 - ("taxidermist", "Buckingham spates hairlines")
 - ("temporized", "dart custodian dissimulating")
 - ("tumid", "peyote titbit bemusing Alpert")
 - ("vertebrates", "propensities somewhats cinchonas")
 - ("watchers", "disproving tiaras unbinding")
```

Comment: hi @sehe, thanks for the great answer, however I am using node.js for this application. What I want to do is being able to place the text file in memory, and later being able to retrieve a random line of it.

Comment: I have updated my answer replying the questions you asked.

Comment: That module does exactly the same thing as my code, except with `Dict` being `unordered_map<string, Cell>` where `Cell` is a poor-man's `variant<string, double>`. So, you will still be doing exactly the same. The code is here by the way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmap-object?activeTab=readme. I can't say the code looks good, but it should work. I cannot get the node side of things working for me (node versions etc. https://imgur.com/a/r91MUEJ

Comment: mmap-object code works well, and it's very fast indeed. But my doubt here is the memory allocation. Do you have any idea why it takes more than the double of the actual text file bytes? With larger files it takes even 3x-4x the actual bytes.

Comment: I have created a [repository](https://github.com/monteiz/mmap-object-memory-issue} with the working test code.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't map the original file. At all. It puts the hash-table in memory, where all javascript types other than `float` are represented as their JSON serialized text.

Comment: I'd maybe suggest a simple index over the raw mapped region. That's simple enough, but I'm not too familiar with node to show the node side extension to access it. Here's the basic idea in c++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d31327a615a5a4e5

Comment: "all javascript types other than float are represented as their JSON serialized text". Where did you see that in the code?

Comment: Indeed, your index solution would absolutely be the best approach for this case. I wish @allen (mmap-object author) could integrate it in his package. While I am at least rusty in C++, I have absolutely zero experience with Node.js C++ addons, which makes it very hard for me to create a dedicated package.

Comment: I linked to the source code. It's the Cell type (which i described as a poor man's variant in that comment). I'll see whether I can find time later to look at your GitHub project. The chance that mmap-object will integrate your wish is below zero, as it's just unrelated. Also, i would suggest you could do this without boost easily, simplifying distribution immensely

Comment: You're totally right. I'll try to publish a node add-on using your approach. For the first release I will necessarily use boost though, because I'm too rusty in C++ to try without it. I will share here the repo. Tomorrow I will assign you the bounty, it's still locked for the next 7 hours.

Comment: I was also trying my hand, but all the node stuff is frustrating me :) It seems as though [Node nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/HEAD/doc/node_misc.md#api_nan_module_init) is not compatible with any node version I try. It's one of those learning curve thresholds. So, if you share your work I might be able to speed up :)

Comment: OMG I cannot believe I spent hours to combat a serious type incompatibility, that the devs just dismiss as "not worth fixing" https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/807 . Okay then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252290/discussion-between-sehe-and-luca-fagioli).